# Azure Pipeline - Use Script Task Variable as parameter in template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the following challenge,

```
# main pipeline

...

stages:
- stage: StageA
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    steps:
    - bash: |

        ...

        $env=dev
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ENVIRONMENT;isOutput=true]$env"
      name: TaskA

    - template: template.yml@templatesRepo
      parameters:
        ENVIRONMENT: ${{ variables.ENVIRONMENT }} # or $(ENVIRONMENT) ## both do not work

        ...
```

```
# template

parameters:
  - name: ENVIRONMENT
    type: string

...

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: AzRM-${{ parameters.ENVIRONMENT }}
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
          
          ...

      addSpnToEnvironment: true

...
```

Now the issue is that the ENVIRONMENT parameter in the template does not expand. It stays blank, because I guess the `AzRM-${{ parameters.ENVIRONMENT }}` in the template get evaluated before the code in the main pipeline runs and the variable is set.

Is there a way to get around this? I have tried quite a few things, such as multi-stage, multi-jobs, different kinds of annotations (compile time vs. runtime) (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) but nothing helped.

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible?

Thanks and regards

Comment: No, you can't use variables set at runtime as parameters. Parameters are resolved at template compilation time. You can avoid having an `environment` parameter entirely by using multi-stage pipelines, one stage for each environment. You say you've tried multi-stage pipelines, but you haven't explained *what* you tried or what didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann! The environment parameter is actually one of many parameters I set in that task. Hence having a stage per environment wouldn't help me I think. 
What I had tried, was to set the variables in a different stage, and then use them in the following. But this didn't help either.
But I guess I will have to find a whole other way. Perhaps starting the pipeline manually instead and set the parameters I need :-(

Comment: No, runtime variables are runtime variables **regardless** of where you set them. Parameters need to be resolvable at template compilation time (which occurs basically the second you click the queue button and are presented with the options UI, and recompiles every time you change a parameter), end of story.

Comment: Thank you sir! That's exactly what I end up understanding, but wasn't sure. Thanks for confirming this